# How to port cookie.Value from .NET 5 to .NET 6/7? (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, cookies, split

The code in question is:

```
var arrVal = cookie.Value.Split('.');
```

I tried the following syntax according to the documentation, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
var arrVal = cookie["Value"].Split('.');
```

For context rest of the code:

```
public IList<CookieType> GetAcceptedCookieTypes(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    var result = new List<CookieType>();

    // accepted by default
    result.Add(CookieType.Essential);

    var cookie = httpContext.Request.Cookies["cc_cookie_accept"];

    if (cookie != null)
    {
        var arrVal = cookie.Value.Split('.');

        if (arrVal != null && arrVal.Length > 1)
        {
            var arrCheck = arrVal[1];

            if (arrCheck.Length > 0 && arrCheck[0] == '1')
            {
                result.Add(CookieType.Statistical);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no accessible extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I'm not aware of any changes to cookies between ASP.NET Core 5 and 6. What error are you getting, exactly?

Comment: I checked the docs and `IRequestCookieCollection[String]` [has **always** returned `string?` going back to ASP.NET Core 1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.irequestcookiecollection.item?view=aspnetcore-1.0). Your code could not have compiled [against ASP.NET Core 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.irequestcookiecollection.item?view=aspnetcore-5.0) where the only change was to add the nullable annotation.

Comment: Anyway. to fix it just remove the `.Value` part.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have solved it! Please answer properly so that I can accept it as an answer too ^^

Comment: I note that in ASP.NET for .NET Framework (2001-2015) the `Request.Cookies` collection _did_ return `System.Web.HttpCookie` objects which _do_ have a `.Value` property, but that's not .NET 5 at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the docs and `IRequestCookieCollection[String]` [has **always** returned `string?` going back to ASP.NET Core 1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.irequestcookiecollection.item?view=aspnetcore-1.0). Your code could not have compiled [against ASP.NET Core 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.irequestcookiecollection.item?view=aspnetcore-5.0) where the only change was to add the nullable annotation.

I note that in ASP.NET for .NET Framework (2001-2015) the `Request.Cookies` collection *did* return [`System.Web.HttpCookie` objects which *do* have a `.Value` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcookie?view=netframework-4.8), but that's not .NET 5 at all.

Anyway. to fix it just remove the `.Value` part.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at this recently, and the documentation seems to conflict a little. In Net 6 Core, the cookie always returns a string, unless I missed something there is no `Value` property. I'm using VS2022. I haven't added anything special to my project for this to work.

So I did this

Created a model with the things I want to store

```
public class CookieDataViewModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Then to store the cookie, I do this

```
CookieOptions loginCookie = new() { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), Path = "/" };

CookieDataViewModel cookieDataViewModel = new CookieDataViewModel { UserId = user.ID, Language = "en" };

string cookieData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cookieDataViewModel);

Response.Cookies.Append(userCookieName, cookieData, loginCookie);
```

And to get it back I do this

```
CookieDataViewModel? cookieDataViewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CookieDataViewModel>(cookie);

... cookieDataViewModel.UserId ...
... cookieDataViewModel.Language ...
```

This works perfectly for what I need :)